# Xamarin.Forms Toolbar Item Icon Size

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, toolbar

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL project and I am trying to add a Toolbar to my App as below and my target platform is UWP.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="attach.png" Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
    <ToolbarItem Icon="camera.png" Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Item1" Order="Secondary" Priority="1" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Item2" Order="Secondary" Priority="2" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Item3" Order="Secondary" Priority="3" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Item4" Order="Secondary" Priority="4" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I have added all icon sources to root folder of UWP project. When i run the app on Windows 10 Desktop, icons appears too small. Orginal size of the image is okay though. 
[image]

I would be appreciated if someone know how to fix this.

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your issue in my side. And I have used the same icon in UWP and xamarin.forms to do a comparison. They do not make any difference in size.

[image]

The size of `ToolbarItem` icon is fixed. If you used icon with text description, then the image will look very small, in case of which you can set ToolBarItem     `Text` property. When you click `More Button`, ToolbarItems will be expanded so that the text can be display well. And you'd better use a image whose active area is big enough.

```
<ToolbarItem Icon="camera.png" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Text="camera"/>
```

[image]